# Writing to Access 2010 Database

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am trying to write to an access 2010 databse using vb.net. I had it working but I had to delete the old database and make a new one, and not it's not working. Here is the code I have:

```
    Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb"
    Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
    cnn.Open()

    'Naming the new Row in Query1.
    Dim newQuery1Row As FortedbDataSet.Query1Row
    newQuery1Row = Me.FortedbDataSet1.Query1.NewQuery1Row()

    'Making the first row the date.
    newQuery1Row.ProdDate = GlobalVariables.mdbProdDate
    newQuery1Row.BaleLine = GlobalVariables.mdbBaleLine
    newQuery1Row.BaleNumber = GlobalVariables.mdbBaleNumber
    newQuery1Row.GrossWeight = GlobalVariables.mdbGrossWeight
    newQuery1Row.AirDry = GlobalVariables.mdbAirDry
    newQuery1Row.InvoiceWeight = GlobalVariables.mdbInvoiceWeight

    'Adding the row to the table.
    Me.FortedbDataSet1.Query1.Rows.Add(newQuery1Row)

    cnn.Close()

    'Saving the row in Access.
    Me.Query1TableAdapter.Update(Me.FortedbDataSet1.Query1)
```

When I made my new database I had to make new **DataSet**, **TableAdpater**, and I also made a connection to the new database. I must be overlooking something.

Comment: Define "it's not working", what is the exception message? stack trace?

Comment: It isn't giving me an error message. It runs fine, but is not saving to my database. I'm not entirely sure what is happening.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing how you defined the dataset and tableadapter

Comment: I have taken out all of my databse connections and datasets and restarted he connections and no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I decided that I would go with an SQL statement to solve the problem.

`Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
        mystr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb"
        connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(mystr)
        connection.Open()
        'Inserting the data into the database.
        mydb = "INSERT INTO b_forte (ProdDate, BaleLine, BaleNumber, GrossWeight, AirDry, InvoiceWeight) VALUES ('" & mdbProdDate & "', '" & mdbBaleLine & "', '" & mdbBaleNumber & "', '" & mdbGrossWeight & "', '" & mdbAirDry & "', '" & mdbInvoiceWeight & "')"
        Dim run = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Try
            run = New OleDbCommand(mydb, connection)
            run.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()`